# What's the probability of getting at least half of successes in N Bernoulli trials?

Tags: probability

I've stumbled onto this problem and have been struggling to find a solution.

We have a biased coin - $P(H)=0.25$ and $P(T)=0.75$. Given $N$ trials, what's the probability that at least half of the results is heads?

I belive this boils down to solving this equasion, but am not sure if this is correct and how to solve it:

$P(m>\frac{N}2)=\sum_{i=N/2}^N {N \choose i}(0.25)^i(0.75)^{N-i} $

Is the above equation correct and how can I solve it?
Can we find what is *expected value* of this probability?

Comment: What do you call the expected value of a (deterministic) number?

Comment: "Can we find what is expected value of this probability?" No, because the probability is a single number, while expected values are calculated for random variables.

Comment: This question came up while discussing it with others and I think it was intended to ask if we can calculate expected value as N approaches infinity.

Comment: Unrelated to the objection.

Comment: Thank you for your kind comments. I understand now that expected value is not the right term here. 
As we increase N, what will be that probability? Is it approaching 0, 1 or maybe a different value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sum is (almost) correct if m is the number of heads obtained (even if random variables are usually labeled with capital letters). You should use $\ge$ in the argument of P because of the "at least" requirement. If N is not too big, the sum can be calculated. If N is (very) big, you can use some approximation for the Binomial distribution, for instance the Poisson approximation or the Normal approximation, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution. According to the latter, the number of heads is asymptotically normally distributed with mean $N \cdot 0.25$ and standard deviation $\sqrt{N \cdot 0.25 \cdot 0.75}$. The desired probability can then be expressed using the CDF of the normal distribution like this: $$ P(X \ge N/2) = 1 - P(X \le N/2 - 1) = 1 - F_x(N/2 -1) = 1 - \Phi \left(\frac{N/2-1 - N\cdot 0.25}{\sqrt{N \cdot 0.25 \cdot 0.75}} \right)$$  Here, $\Phi$ is the CDF of the standard normal distribution. To make it even better, you can use some continuity correction, see for instance https://onlinecourses.science.psu.edu/stat414/node/179. The value
$N \cdot 0.25$ is also the expected value of the random variable X (not of the probability). You expect $N \cdot 0.25$ heads if you toss N times, which is very intuitive.

Comment: Thank you for a very constructive answer, even if the question may not have been very clear!